# How to change the color to red when i seleced the tabs ,and changed to black when i unselected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

https://github.com/iltercengiz/ICViewPager

I download it form github,and make something little changed,

but one question I can't fix it:

when I select a tab, I want the selected tab's text change to red,and unselected tab's text changed to black,

I look over of this code,and I don't how and where to add code to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to write an email to the creator. Yo can find his email at the bottom of his gitHub page. I think He could help you, anyway, He says:

> Note (to everyone who is interested in ViewPager): I cannot have much
>   time to improve ViewPager for a long time, but I have some cool plans
>   for it. So if you encounter any problems, bugs or etc. please forgive
>   me, and send some pull requests. Thank you for your interest and
>   support.

Luck

Comment: thank you! I take it down already!:) you remind me to find the answer form the github,someone fixed it,i am  a nuts!

Answer (score 0):

I found it from someone

```
UILabel *labelSubview;
// Set to-be-inactive tab unselected
activeTabView = [self tabViewAtIndex:self.activeTabIndex];
activeTabView.selected = NO;
labelSubview = activeTabView.subviews[0];
labelSubview.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

// Set to-be-active tab selected
activeTabView = [self tabViewAtIndex:activeTabIndex];
activeTabView.selected = YES;
labelSubview = activeTabView.subviews[0];
labelSubview.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```